# What does order=0 mean in mem-info data (Orders are powers of two allocations, so does it mean no pages were being allocated?)

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory

foobar.exe invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0

What is an order=0 allocation?  That's less than one page, so is it like a kmalloc32 or something smaller than page_size?  Linux 3.x kernel x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An order of 0 *is* one page.

> page allocation order
>
> The 'order' of a page allocation is it's logarithm to the base 2, and the size of the allocation is 2<sup>order</sup>, an integral power-of-2 number of pages. 'Order' ranges from from 0 to MAX_ORDER-1.
>
> The smallest - and most frequent - page allocation is 2<sup>0</sup> or 1 page.

(https://linux-mm.org/PageAllocation#page_allocation_order)

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I wasnt thinking that 1 ** 2 == 1, for some reason I was thinking zero, that was silly.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal, it is zero, 2 ** 0 = 1, it's just that the unit is pages, not bytes.